# innerText resulting in [object HTMLLIElement] instead of the li text

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-manipulation

Beginner here.

I'm in the process of building a simple to do website with Javascript. The website allows you to set a title for the task and add steps too.

I'm having some troubles displaying task steps once you add the task to the task list.

The following code:

```js
let data = document.getElementById('task-steps-new');
let dataList = data.childNodes;

let list = document.querySelector('.task-ul');

dataList.forEach((item)=> {
  li = document.createElement('li');
  li.innerText = item;
  list.appendChild(li);
});
```

displays the task steps as [object HTMLLIElement] instead of the actual text. Cannot wrap my head around why it's not working, so any help would be greatly appreciated! I've also added below the whole function which grabs the task title input and steps and moves it to the task list. Everything works except the issue stated above.

```js
function addTask() {
    const inputValue = document.getElementById("add-task").value;
    const newTask = document.createElement('h2');
    const t = document.createTextNode(inputValue);
    const stepList = document.getElementById('task-steps-new');
    const newUl = document.createElement('ul');
    const newLi = document.createElement('li');

    newTask.appendChild(t);

    if (inputValue === '') {
        alert("You must type something!")
    } else {
        newLi.className = "task";
        newTask.className = "task-title";
        newUl.className = "task-ul";
        document.querySelector(".task-list").appendChild(newLi);    
        newLi.appendChild(newTask);
        newLi.appendChild(newUl);

        let data = document.getElementById('task-steps-new');
        let dataList = data.childNodes;

        let list = document.querySelector('.task-ul');

        dataList.forEach((item)=> {
            li = document.createElement('li');
            li.innerText = item;
            list.appendChild(li);
        }); 
        
    }
    document.getElementById("add-task").value = "";
    stepList.innerHTML = '';
    
    var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
    var txt = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");
    span.className = "close";
    span.appendChild(txt);
    newLi.appendChild(span);

    for (i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
        close[i].onclick = function() {
            var div = this.parentElement;
            div.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `li.innerText = item.innerText`

Comment: Thats it! Thank you! One more thing now. It also displays the 'x' which is the delete button for the step. How can I get around to displaying just the text, not the 'x'?

Comment: Put them in separate elements, and use `querySelectorAll()` to select just the elements that have the text you want to copy.

Comment: I did it slightly differently. Instead of using text as a close button, I made it create an i class to use a font awesome close icon and now it works! Thanks for you help!